# Which one of these are right?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, difference

I read this example

> Flying high above the trees, the butterfly was impossible to catch

I thought that the sentence must have been made like this:

> Flying.....,the butterfly was impossible to be caught.

Which one of those is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is correct as it is:

> The butterfly was impossible to catch.

This construction is an example of "*tough* movement", as explained here:
[Wikipedia "Tough movement"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_movement)

> In formal syntax, **tough** movement refers to sentences in which the syntactic subject of the main verb is logically the object of an embedded non-finite verb. The following sentences illustrate *tough* movement.
>
> 1. This problem is tough to solve.
> 2. Chris is easy to please.

So, in your example, **butterfly** is the subject of **is**, and it is also logically the object of **to catch**.

(The word "tough" is used to describe the grammar phenomenon because, like "impossible" in your example, it's one of a class of words that can be used in that construction. The linked article has a list of such words.)